# Getting multiple types from same Morphia Query

Tags: java, mongodb, polymorphism, morphia

I have a Mongo Collection with multiple different kinds of objects in it.  All of these classes form a tree that inherits from a common abstract base called "Event".  There are many different kinds of Events, and I put them all into the same collection.

I want to write a Morphia query to get all the Events, and I want them deserialized back into their original Java classes.

I was hoping that I could do this query, but it does not seem to work.  I get 0 objects.

```
Query query = mongo.createQuery(Event.class);
List<Event> events = query.asList();
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 1):

Is Event abstract?  The generated query is going to include the classname which will never match the subclasses.  You seem to be running in to this [open issue](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/22).

Comment: Oh dear.  I may be out of luck.  Yes, I don't actually want any Events.  I want classes that all inherit from Event.  e.g. ThisEvent, ThatEvent...